# proof of one sided limit

Tags: calculus

> Find $$lim_{x \to 1} \frac{x^2+x-2}{(x-1)^2}$$

$$lim_{x \to 1} \frac{x^2+x-2}{(x-1)^2}=lim_{x \to 1} \frac{(x-1)(x+2)}{(x-1)^2}=lim_{x \to 1} \frac{(x+2)}{(x-1)}$$

So there is not limit

$$lim_{x \to 1^{-}} \frac{(x+2)}{(x-1)}=lim_{x \to 1^{-}} \frac{(x-1+3)}{(x-1)}=lim_{x \to 1^{-}} 1+\frac{3}{(x-1)}$$ therefore the limit is $-\infty$ and the same goes for $lim_{x \to 1^{+}}$?
is it a formal answer?

Comment: The limit indeed does not exist, which can be confirmed with a graph (which is always a good idea to see what's going on) What is happening if $x$ approaches $1$ from the left hand side?

Comment: it is $\frac{3}{-\frac{1}{\infty}}=-\infty$

Answer (score 0):

The limit does not exist. There is a difference between a limit of $\infty$ or $-\infty$ and a limit that does not exist. If you want to show that the limit does not exist, you have to show that the limit as approached from the left and the right are different values.

Approaching from the left, the limit is $-\infty$, while approaching from the right, the limit is $\infty$. Since it is the case that these values differ, then there is no limit as $x$ approaches 1 (since we are unable to reconcile the two different answers).

Edit: As pointed out in the comments, it is also sufficient to show that either the limit from the left or the right do not exist. In this case however, the limit from the left does indeed exist (-$\infty$), and you therefore need to consider the approach from the right.

Comment: For a function f, the right limit or the left limit in a may be not defined. example: f(x)= cos(1/x) when x tends to 0. Neither le left limit neither the right limit exists.